# Cannot Keep Mapped Drives Connected With Saved Credentials

Tags: sharepoint-server, mapped-folder

I thought this was a problem with Windows Server 2012 and earlier only, but I'm finding the same problem on a new Windows 2019 Server. I am trying to map drives to my local SharePoint 2007 and my SharePoint 2013. The mapped drive works fine the first time, but after every reboot, they come back with red 'X's and force me to click on each mapped drive and re-enter the login/password. I've tried several suggestions, but nothing will keep the credentials and auto-reconnect the mapped drives.

The logged-on Windows user has full access to the SharePoint sites.

I followed the steps here:
https://adamtheautomator.com/map-sharepoint-drive/

and here:
https://logiccloudit.com/knowledge-base/map-a-sharepoint-document-library-as-a-network-drive/

I tried using 'net use /persistent:yes', File Explorer 'Reconnect' and 'Remember credentials'.

I've tried both UNC and URL paths.

I also tried setting up a Network Location File Folder but acts the same.

I added a shortcut on startup that automatically opens the SharePoint site via iexplorer, but I still have to open and log on to each mapped drive.

It's only the mapped drives pointing to SharePoint that have this problem, other mapped drives to network servers work fine.

Can anyone think of any way to get this to work?